# Convert highlight clicked row code from JQuery to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and MVC and I have a javascript that highlights the clicked row. However, in my code I noticed that using a `table-striped` class will not highlight the odd rows, only the even ones. Also it only highlights the row once the mouse lose focus on the clicked row. Here's my current JS:

```
function getrowval(tableId, columnData, txtBoxId) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
    var cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        var cell = cells[i];
        cell.onclick = function () {
            var rowId = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
            var rowsNotSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for (var row = 0; row < rowsNotSelected.length; row++) {
                rowsNotSelected[row].style.backgroundColor = "";
                rowsNotSelected[row].classList.remove('selected');
            }
            var rowSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[rowId];

            rowSelected.className += "selected";

            //Here's where I'm having an issue
            rowSelected.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";

            document.getElementById(txtBoxId).value = rowSelected.cells[columnData].innerHTML.trim();

            var status = rowSelected.cells[2].innerHTML.trim();
            if (status == "Active") {
                document.getElementById("rActive").checked = true;
            } else
            {
                document.getElementById("rInactive").checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My css:

```
.selected {
    color: red;
}
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

My table in cshtml:

```
<table id="dbTbl" onclick="gettabledata('dbTbl', '1', 'txtUsername')" class="table table-scroll table-hover table-striped bootgrid-table" aria-busy="false">
```

And here's the link (not mine) where the highlight is working in `table-striped`, I want the JQuery here to be implemented in my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/xu2AH/9/

For those who are too lazy to visit the link, the code below is the one I want to convert to Javascript so I can insert it to my code above:

```
$('#mytable tbody tr').live('click', function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: The code you showed above is javascript, but using jQuery helper methods for easy dom access. You want to convert it to pure javascript again ? Is there a specific reason you want to do that ?

Comment: `For those who are lazy to visit the link` ... for those too lazy to post code in the question, I suggest javascript 101 as that jquery is trivial to un-jquerify :p

Comment: What I only want is to copy the jquery code from jsfiddle link and paste it into my javascript code above. This code doesn'y higlight the odd rows because it's already altered by `table-striped` class: `rowSelected.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";`

Comment: I'll update my question and add the `table-striped` css

Comment: The jsfiddle you posted highlight any row when clicked. What is wrong ?

Comment: Hi Shyju, yes the code in jsfiddle is working, the code is not mine and I want my javascript code to function like that. The problem with my javascript is that it only highlight the even ones, I assume it's because of my `table-striped` class overriding my JS. What I'm planning to do is get that jquery in jsfiddle and paste it in my javascript code

Comment: I noticed that the `table-striped` in the jsfiddle is different from my `table-striped`. I'm trying to copy the css from jsfiddle